# Problema para verificar si existe un usaurio: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un problema con ésta consulta para verificar si el usuario existe o no. Busqué por internet y me encontré con la función mysqli_num_rows. Posteriormente la incluí a mi código por medio de un IF, el cual verifica si encontró algún registro. Al probar siempre me envía al último ELSE, el cual dice <>.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexion.php");
$conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $pass, $database) or die("Fallo en la conexión con la base de datos.");
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$database);

$codigo       = $_POST['cod_u'];
$contra       = $_POST['contra'];

$_SESSION['codigo'] = $codigo;
$_SESSION['contra'] = $contra;
$verificar = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE codigo = '$codigo'");
$sql = mysqli_fetch_array($verificar);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
  // si el numero es igual a 0 es porque el registro no exite
  if(!empty($sql) AND $sql['contra'] != $contra){
    echo"<script>alert('La contraseña es incorrecta. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo.'); window.location='editar.html';</scritp>";
  }else{
    echo"<script>alert('Bienvenido $nombre'); window.location='info.html';</scritp>";
  }
}else{
  echo"El estudiante no se encuenta registrado.";
}


/*
if($sql['codigo'] == $codigo  AND $sql['contra'] == $contra){
        echo"<script>alert('Bienvenido $nombre'); window.location='info.php';</script>";
}else{
      echo"<script>alert('Error al iniciar sesión.'); window.location='editar.html';</scritp>";
}*/
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quien tiene el objeto `mysqli_result` es quien ejecutó `mysqli_query`, que en tu caso es `$verificar`. Por eso el error te indica: *`mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`*, o sea, el parámetro que le estás pasando no es un `mysqli_result`.

El problema debería resolverse si pones esta línea así:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar) > 0){
```

Aunque hay otros errores de lógica y código redundante. Si te interesa puedo sugerirte algunas modificaciones más lógicas, pero primero prueba a corregir el problema principal que nos atañe.